# Notification sound not working on mobile browswer's

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a javascript code like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function addmsg(count, play){
        if(play == 'true')
        {               
            $("#my_audio").get(0).play();
        }
        }

</script>
<html>
  <audio id="my_audio" src="popsound.mp3"></audio>
</html>
```

In the above code "play" variable is like a flag containing true or false value, and it plays the sound when play=='true'.The above code is working fine on my laptop browser,but when I'm accessing the page through my mobile the sound doesnt gets played. I did some research but I'm unable to figure out how to do it in my case. I'm very new to this field so sorry if this question is senseless, but can any one please help me. I wanted to make it work fine for mobile browser's too.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put different formats for all devices (.ogg and .mp3).

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: When I triggered the same function by creating button and clicking it  using onclick event it did played that sound even in mobile.

Comment: There is maybe something here : www.mediaflash.ca/jimscroll/examples/navigationV.html :)

Comment: I think mobile browser is coded in such a way that it do not autoplay the audio/video so think maybe that's the reason  i'm facing this issue.